# How To Apply Multiple Filters Or Daisy Chian At Request SQL

Tags: c#, sql

moral of the story im not asking for my work done for me, im asking where could one find information or how could one possibly go about  appling multiple filters if the filter is requested in the selection but not automatically enforced. 
As to select all rows from say example a  property database Table.
Then filter out unneccisary rows "Properties" by applying a filter Or even multiple filters at users choice of selected dropdown 
Example having filters of MonthlyRent Column,Status Column and say PropertyType colomn 
say user is looking for Something Specific a 2 bedroom trailer
i Can Apply Filters From My Front End Of My C# Program  To look In the selected data for the key filters of bedroom 2 and Type trailer status vacant

how would one go about applying a somehwat of a daisy chain if multiple filters need to be applied But Not Automatically Enforced Unless Specified. Any Info Or Guidance IS Appreciated Thanks For Reading 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to generate a query based on the selected filters, there isn't really a question here that is specific or answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following SQL

```
SELECT propertyStatusColumn FROM [[TABLE NAME]] 
WHERE
propertyLocation = [[User provided location]] AND
propertyType = [[User provided property type]] AND
bedroomNumber= [[User provided bedroom number]] AND
monthlyRent = [[User provided rent rnage]]
```

Comment: Thank you I thought about doing the  WHERE AND statements but I Was just afraid if user dont select or use that filter it might still automatically try to enforce it with the search. Which just assuming it wouldnt give the results the user was looking for  Which im Sure One Could Run Through If Statements Dropdown value = whatever execute this query BUT thatd be alot of if statements